# 'top' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

'onscroll' class not added to edge and internet explorer This two browser show an error top is undefined or null referance. It works fine on all other browser including chrome, firefox and safari.

```
    var s = $(".lgx-header-position");
    var pos = s.position();

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("menu-onscroll");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("menu-onscroll");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I [can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/nvz0q7Lu/) with Edge ..?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n30u1rdv/1/ Try this link

Comment: Please edit your question and click the snippet button to create a [mcve].  There are too many unanswered issues in your question.  Eg what's `.lgx-header-position`?  when do you call `s.position()`? do you check `pos` before using it?

Comment: Actually it works Proper.